# What is the difference between an oauth2 server flow that is requested from the browser vs inside angular app via http?

Tags: angularjs, oauth-2.0, cors, tornado, google-oauth

I have a server side oauth2 flow that works if you type it in to the browser like this:

```
https://<my-server-domain>/connect/google
```

I have a tornado server that issues the redirect to an appropriately setup google app.  The redirect works successfully and the browser brings up the google permissions screen.

I am trying to invoke the same process from within my Angular app using $http but I keep getting the well known: XMLHttpRequest cannot load...error due to No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin" present on the requested resource.

I am invoking the $http request as follows:

```
            return $http({ method: 'GET',
                      url: server+query,
                      headers: {
                          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                          'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true',
                          'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST, GET,OPTIONS'
                        }}).success(function(data){...
```

I recognize that there are other methods for doing this AND that there is a google+ flow in the documentation that I could move to.  However,  I don't understand what the difference is between typing in a browser request for the same resource that I am requesting via the $http service.  Why would they yield different results ( one successful, the other unsuccessful).

I should also note that I could also run the entire oauth2 flow server side successfully as well but for this use case I need the user to authenticate and give permission via the app.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Those headers must be returned in the *response*, not specified in the request.  I suspect you're not serving your Angular app from `<my-server-domain>`, and that you'd get that error from any XHR, not just Angular's.  See the [MDN page for CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) for some good information.

Comment: I am serving the app from the same domain.  specifically:  http://<my-seriver-domain>/app/index.html

Comment: Additionally,  if i use the following code instead of http request:  window.location.assign('<my-server-domain>/connect/google')     it works as well.  Only the http request fails

Comment: 1) Was the http in your last comment (instead of https) just a typo or is that an actual difference?  2) Have you done any server-side configuration or coding to return the needed headers? XMLHttpRequest does the enforcement. 3)  In my link to the MDN CORS page it describes that the browser sets the Origin: header -- using a wire protocol inspector (Fiddler2, Charles, Wireshark) you should be able to see what's getting set for the Origin: field.  Hope these help.